Fundamental group of genus $g$ surface with $n$ points removed
I am currently following the only answer to this old question. I do not understand what is meant by "$\pi_1(A\cap B)$ just kills off one generator..."
In what follows, I take $U$ and $V$ as in the above post. Let $\iota_{UV}:\pi_1(U\cap V)\to \pi_1(U)$ denote the map induced by the inclusion of $U\cap V $ into $U$. From what I understand, if $X$ is the genus $g$ surface with $n$ punctures, then $\pi_1(X) \cong \frac{\pi_1(U) * \pi_1(V)}{N}$ where $N = \langle \{\iota_{UV}(\omega)\iota_{VU}(\omega)^{-1}, \omega \in \pi_1(U\cap V)\}\rangle$ via the Seifert van-Kampen theorem. I am aware that $\pi_1(U\cap V)$ is infinite cyclic, and thus equal to $\langle f \rangle$ for some path homotopy class $f$ belonging to the intersection.
Now, $f$ includes into $\pi_1(U)$ as a product of commutants $[a_1, b_1][a_2, b_2]...[a_{g-1}, b_{g-1}]$ where $a_i$ and $b_i$ generate each hole of $U$. However, I am unsure of how $f$ includes into $\pi_1(V)$, and how ultimately one generator is "killed off" after taking the quotient by $N$.
